# Criteria for public modulus of RSA accumulator

Tags: rsa, key-generation, accumulators

**What are criteria for generation of an RSA public modulus used in an RSA accumulator, and their rationale? Are there special requirements in some sub-cases, like for «one-way» accumulators?**

---

Josh Benaloh and Michael de Mare's [*One-way accumulators: A decentralized alternative to digital signatures*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1993/01/owa.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1993](https://doi.org10.1007/3-540-48285-7_24), prescribes the public modulus to be a *rigid integer*. That's defined as $\,n\,=\,p\,q\,$ with $p$ and $q$ [safe primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) and $\,|p|\,=\,|q|\,$ (equal bit size). Then $\,n=(2p'+1)\,(2q'+1)\,$ with $p$, $p'$, $q$, $q'$ (large) primes. The subgroup of [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has order $n'=p'\,q'$. And the function $e_{n,y}(x)\underset{\text{def}}=x^y\bmod n\,$ is a permutation of this group when $\gcd(y,n)=1$. The authors argue:

> Thus, if the factorization of $n$ is hidden, “random” exponentiations of an
> element of this group are extremely unlikely to produce elements of any proper subgroup. This means that repeated applications of $e_n(x,y)$ are extremely unlikely to reduce the size of the domain or produce random collisions.

More precisely, what kind of disaster can strike if we used random primes? Is there a positive security argument relying on safe primes? Also, is there a justification for $\,|p|\,=\,|q|\,$ beyond getting $\,|p|\approx|q|\,$, which helps against [ECM factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization)?

---

What about the different recommendations in Michael T. Goodrich, Roberto Tamassia, Jasminka Hasic's [*An Efficient Dynamic and Distributed RSA Accumulator*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1307.pdf#page=8) ([arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1307), 2009), originally [in proceedings of ISC 2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45811-5_29)? They ask *strong primes* without justification, referencing the [HAC's definition](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap4.pdf#page=18):

> A prime number $p$ is said to be a *strong prime* if integers $r$, $s$, and $t$ exist such that the following three conditions are satisfied:
>  (i)    $p−1$ has a large prime factor, denoted $r$;
>  (ii)   $p+1$ has a large prime factor, denoted $s$; and
>  (iii)  $r−1$ has a large prime factor, denoted $t$.

When the application is RSA signature and encryption, these requirements are obsoleted¹ by the need to dimension $\,n\,=\,p\,q\,$ for resistance to [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). Are these requirements appropriate in the case of RSA accumulators, and if so for what quantitative meaning of *large*?

---

¹ [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=59) appendix B.3 drops these requirements for 1024-bit or larger primes, and that seems conservative. There's a discussion in Ronald L. Rivest and Robert D. Silverman's [Are ‘Strong’ Primes Needed for RSA?](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS01.version-1999-11-22.pdf), but it does not consider the interest of (i) and (ii) in multi-target attacks, where the adversary's goal is to factor any of many public moduli.